# Syntax Error in Basic Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I keep getting errors when debugging in IE.
This is a basic hide function.

idHide is the id of the field to be hidden
idCondition is the id of the reference field the condition is compared upon
value is the value that would satisfy the condition

```
function hideOnCondition(idHide, idCondition, value)
{    
    if (document.getElementById[idCondition] = value)
    {    
        document.getElementById(idHide).style.display = "none";         
    }
    else
    {           
        document.getElementById(idHide).style.display = "";
    }
}
```

I always encounter the error in:

```
if (document.getElementById[idCondition] = value)
```

> "the value of the property is null or undefined not a function object"

Then I tried changing "getElementById" with "all". then changed the brackets to parentheses, still nothing, only for the line to be highlighted in yellow.

Im sorry, I'm just stumped. Again, thank you all for understanding.

Comment: `=` should be `==`. Also I have to admit I've never seen `document.getElementById` treated like an associative array

Comment: Do you know that comparison uses `==`?

Comment: What is the syntax error? Please share a working snippet using `<>` in your toolbar.

Comment: There is no syntax error, there is a runtime error and it is listed in the question. The question's title is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction(option, value, div) {

    //get the element you want to hide by it's ID
    var x = document.getElementById(div); 

    //if the option you selected is coresponding to the given value 
    //hide the earlier selected element
    if (option === value) {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get what your code does. Ill try to apply it to mine,

Answer (score 1):

- You were using square brackets instead of parentheses
- `===` should be used for comparing not `=`

.

```
function hideOnCondition(idHide, idCondition, value)
{    
    if (document.getElementById(idCondition) === value) // <- fix here
    {    
        document.getElementById(idHide).style.display = "none";         
    }
    else
    {           
        document.getElementById(idHide).style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: that I did not know, I was searching for other stuff about the code, but I didn't realize it was the equal sign. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ReginaldMaravilla you're welcome, if this matches what you need then please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) you should use the comparison operator [Identity / strict equality (===)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity):

```
function hideOnCondition(idHide, idCondition, value) {
    const result = document.getElementById[idCondition] === value ? 'none' : '';
    document.getElementById(idHide).style.display = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I could see

- using `=` instead of `===` and not comparing value instead only comparing the the output of `document.getElementById[idCondition]` with value.
- using `[]` instead of invoking the function using `()`

*Although, none of these would cause the syntax error as you have claimed in your post.*

You can simplify it as

```
var getEl = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
function hideOnCondition(idHide, idCondition, value)
{    
    getEl(idHide).style.display = getEl(idCondition).value == value ? "none" : "";
}
```